# Ubuntu 16.04-LTS desktop won't restart or shutdown

Tags: 16.04, shutdown, reboot

I found that on two freshly installed Ubuntu 16.04-LTS desktops, for some reason I can't perform reboot or shutdown. I click on reboot/shutdown in the upper right corner's popup dialog but nothing happens when I chose reboot or shutdown option. It is OK when I do the same in terminal window by issuing `shutdown` or `reboot` command.

Comment: does `sudo init 0` work?

Comment: yes, moreover: when I click on Shutdown or Reboot on my desktop then foloowing message appears in the syslog:

http://pastebin.com/EGvXCRsD

Comment: Might be a kernel issue, as stated in the bug [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1594023). Try with the latest kernel if it fixes the issue.

Comment: Some users have fixed it be editing **/etc/default/grub line:**

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

to

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force"`

then run `sudo update-grub`

[Source](http://askubuntu.com/questions/764568/ubuntu-16-04-hangs-on-shutdown-restart)

Comment: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force"

doesn't work for me.

Comment: Which version of the kernel are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, hard shut-off your computer (Holding the power button down for 10-20 seconds) and turn it on again. Not the most graceful way, but it works.
 Hope this helps!!

Comment: How will this fix the problem that reboot/shutdown dialog doesn't worg ? On top you will risk having to do fsck on your filesystems at next boot and potentially loose data !

Comment: It worked for me, I don't know why but it was very glitchy when I first got ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

OK, finally I found the problem. The problem was with PAM configuration files modified during installation (from local preseed) process.