# no shutdown, kubuntu 16.04.2

Tags: shutdown, acer

I looked for many topics about this, but I didn't succeed in fixing this problem. I decided to upgrade Kubuntu 14.04.5 32 bits --> 16.04.2 32 bits - I have no uefi (using a live-usb, but this problem just appeared after... When I try to shutdown my laptop (Acer Aspire V5-531 series Windows 7 64 bits / Kubuntu 16.04 LTS 32 bits, écran 15,6", 500go DD, 4go RAM, Intel pentium CPU 967 processor, Intel HD graphics 4000), I have those information:

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPrCP.png)

I tried to edit /etc/default/grub by 1) adding 2) replacing "quiet splash" ([Ubuntu 16.04 hangs on shutdown/restart](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764568/ubuntu-16-04-hangs-on-shutdown-restart))

Same thing for /etc/default/halt (replace HALT=poweroff by HALT=shutdown). sudo poweroff -f, shutdown -h now...

What is the source of the problem, I don't even exactly know... I think about creating a script to shutdown. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem: it is a Bios issue. try [THIS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764568/ubuntu-16-04-hangs-on-shutdown-restart) and specifically look at "Turning off USB 3.0 legacy mode in the BIOS worked for me"
if it does not work try manipulating other usb settings.

Comment: I tried the first method (with "sudo swapoff -a && systemctl poweroff"), but I can't try the second one (I haven't software and updates menu in system settings). This time I replaced "quiet splash" by "acpi=force"  AND reduced time out in /etc/systemd/system.conf. But no changes... In this file, I wonder if I must delete a line like "#DefaultRestartSec=100ms" to fix the f**** problem... But I am afraid of making things worse...  There isn't an option about USB 3.0 in the BIOS, only the possibility to change the priority boot (something like USB FFD)