# Ubuntu 16.04 hangs on shutdown/restart (Dell XPS 15 9560)

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, shutdown, restart

I have a Dell XPS 15 (2017) with dual boot (Windows 10 + Ubuntu 16.04).
While trying to install the nvidia drivers (in order to be able to disable the nVidia GPU and let it run on onboard graphics for lower power consumption), my system got messed up. Up until some minutes ago, after shutting down or restarting my computer, I got a black screen with the following output:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p4: recovering journal
/dev/nvme0n1p4: clean, 455620/127927 files, xx/xxx blocks
[xxxx.xxxx] NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#1 stuck for 23s! [plymouthd:13948]
[xxxx.xxxx] NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#1 stuck for 23s! [plymouthd:13948]
INFO: rcu_sched self-detected stall on CPU
o1-...: (14999 ticks this GP) idle=4e5/140000000000/softirq=98156/98156 fqs7496
o (t=xxxxxx jiffies g=xxxxxx c=xxxxxx q=xx
```

[Click here to view the complete log (picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQN5Q.jpg)

After following [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/764568/ubuntu-16-04-hangs-on-shutdown-restart/769972#answer-769972), after step 2, my computer stopped displaying a black screen with the error message above and now only freezes after pressing the shutdown/restart button. Trying `sudo swapoff -a && systemctl poweroff` has the exact same impact.

I have also tried logging the shutdown procedure with no luck so far (run `systemctl start debug-shell` and then hit ctrl+alt+F9 when the hang up occurred, but no response at all.

I am currently using the X.org X server drivers (since after trying one nVidia driver I was unable to open my computer). Additionally, even though I have purged all nVidia drivers, the Additional Drivers dialogue still displays a bunch of them (`nvidia-384 nvidia-375 nvidia-378 nvidia-381`).

I am sorry for the long post-but I tried to supply as much information as possible in order to identify the problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Eventually, the solution that fixed everything for me was the following (at least for my system configuration):

- edit `/etc/default/grub`
- add `acpi_rev_override=1` to your `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` parameters

  (in my case the line looks like this):

  ```
     GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_rev_override=1"
  ```
- run `sudo update-grub` from the terminal

after shutting down your machine one more time from the power button, the problem should have been fixed.

Comment: Solved problem also on  my **XPS 15 9560** with **Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia**

Comment: This doesn't work for me, neither do any of the other posts I've found so far. WTF is going on with Ubuntu?

Comment: I googled quite a bit and noticed that a lot of the posts mention Nvidia drivers. I switched to the proprietary 384.111 driver via the Software center, this seems to have fixed the problem. Now I can shut down or reboot through the terminal or the GUI power button, none of the other posts on line worked for me. Hope this helps someone. Once you switch to the proprietary Nvidia driver, you need to do a hard reboot (via the power button (the physical one)) for the new driver to start working.

Answer (score 2):

I spent so much time on this, but eventually, [the comment by Stefan](https://askubuntu.com/questions/951415/ubuntu-16-04-hangs-on-shutdown-restart-dell-xps-15-9560/1185029#comment1675498_952939) was the solution for me.

As suggested, I switched to the proprietary NVIDIA driver, in my case NVIDIA binary driver- version 384.130 (proprietary, tested).