# Dell XPS 15 ubs boot ubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: boot, dell

I'm trying to boot ubuntu 18.04.1 from my usb slot on my Dell XPS 15, which has Windows 10 as a normal boot. I getting the following error when I try this boot:

```
Invalid signature detected. Check Secure Boot Policy in Setup
```

This more than likely isn't an Ubuntu issue but could someone suggest a solution?
Never had this issue when I booted my XPS 13 with Ubuntu 14.04.
Bios

Comment: New systems are UEFI. But Ubuntu should boot with UEFI Secure Boot on. Dell does often need UEFI update, if SSD that firmware needs updates and drives changed from RAID to AHCI, but add AHCI driver into Windows first.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI & http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi  & http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2317843

Comment: I don't have a SSD drive, do I still need to incorporate the AHCI driver? I believe the bios can be updated, will that solve my issue?

Comment: You still need the AHCI setting & Windows driver. If UEFI needs updates, keep track of UEFI settings you changed. Many may be set back to defaults and need changing again. Dell site: https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/sln301754/how-to-install-ubuntu-and-windows-8-or-10-as-a-dual-boot-on-your-dell-pc?lang=en

Comment: I'm not looking for a dual boot of windows and ubuntu, just want to install ubuntu. Do I still need the ACHI driver. I apologize for initially not making that clear.

Comment: Yes, the desktop version of Ubuntu does not support RAID. And I do not understand why systems with one drive are using a RAID driver, anyway? Server installer will support RAID, but then it expects multiple drives.

Comment: Could u explain why I need to install an AHCI driver under windows when my plan is to install ubuntu over it. In the advance bios setting there is SATA directive which is currently set to "Intel Smart Response Technology", there is also a setting for AHCI. Why can't a reset the SATA setting to AHCI and the boot ubuntu. I'm puzzled at installing the AHCI driver on windows as a prerequisite. I appreciate your assistance.

Comment: If never using Windows again, you do not need AHCI driver. But always best to make full backup of Windows as many user later want Windows back on system, or want to sell system and need Windows to sell it. Then you may need AHCI driver in Windows backup.

Comment: I've moved all files off of W10 and have another platform running that OS. I changed SATA to AHCI and tried to boot from my Ubuntu iso on my usb drive. Unfortunately I still generate the same error msg as before.

Comment: Have you updated UEFI and if SSD, the SSD firmware? And if nVidia video, use nomodemode set for live installer & first boot or until you install nVidia driver from Ubuntu repository? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042414/trying-to-install-ubuntu-on-dell-xps-15-9570 & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046263/dell-xps-15-9570-2018-disable-nvidia-gpu

Comment: Don't have a SSD, did update the BIOS. Is the UEFI update included in BIOS update? If not, have to figure out if I need to update and how

Comment: Many Vendors call the newer UEFI replacement of BIOS as BIOS, since it has been used from the beginning of PCs and most users recognize that name. But since Windows 8, Microsoft has required UEFI with gpt partitioning for all vendor installs of Windows or about last 5 years.

Comment: I can't see any info on UEFI for the XPS 15. Installed the latest BIOS, released on Feb 2018. Checked SATA to ACHI. Disabled Intel Rapid Start Technology. Disabled Secure Boot. Could my iso on my usb be messed up? Would that give the Invalid signature?

Comment: Invalid Signature is UEFI secure boot issue. Is system booting in UEFI mode? As BIOS/CSM/Legacy is not UEFI Secure Boot. Also is Secure boot off, but UEFI on? Or did you not install the signed versions of grub & kernel for UEFI secure boot. But install of proprietary driver requires Secure boot off for now. Post link to summary report. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair Best not to run repairs until someone reviews it.