# Installed Ubuntu 18.04 on Dell XPS15; "No bootable device found"

Tags: boot, usb, boot-repair, xps

I have a Dell XPS15 9570 laptop that came with Windows 10 preinstalled. I decided to remove Windows 10 completely and install Ubuntu 18.04.

I burnt the .iso on my USB drive. I had to change BIOS settings to make the laptop boot from it:

1. **Secure Boot** > **Secure Boot Enable** > uncheck the **Secure Boot Enable** checkbox
2. **General** > **Boot Sequence** > select **Legacy External Devices**
3. Only leave **USB Storage Device** checkbox checked.

After those changes, the Ubuntu 18.04 installer showed up. I erased the whole disk and installed Ubuntu 18.04 on it, however upon restart I see the error message `No bootable device found`.

I reinstalled Ubuntu (prior to that I saw that the Ubuntu installer recognized that there's already a copy of Ubuntu installed) with two partitions, but the problems still persist.

I ran Boot-Repair, and it showed an error and [this link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/38HrhNfpS9/). The error is:

```
grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/sda1. Check your device.map.  
The boot files of [Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS] are far from the start of the disk.   
Your BIOS may not detect them.   
You may want to retry after creating a /boot partition (EXT4, >200MB, start of the disk).   
This can be performed via tools such as GParted.   
Then select this partition via the [Separate /boot partition:] option of Boot-Repair. (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition)
```

Comment: I ran Boot-Repair, it showed an error and this link: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/38HrhNfpS9/

Comment: It looks like you are trying to install in BIOS/Legacy boot mode to new UEFI system. Dells do need UEFI update, SSD firmware update and UEFI setting changed from RAID to AHCI for drives.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI Other 9570 threads: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042414/trying-to-install-ubuntu-on-dell-xps-15-9570 & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046263/dell-xps-15-9570-2018-disable-nvidia-gpu

Comment: Switching from RAID to AHCI solved my problem. Thank you for help.

Comment: You should answer your own question with this solution, to make the community benefit from this.