# Installing dual boot Ubuntu 18.04 on dell xps 15 9570 RAID or AHCI

Tags: boot, dual-boot, dell, raid, ahci

I have recently bought this a new dell xps15 9570 computer.
I have partitioned the windows such that there is a partition with ~650GB empty.
I have followed the instructions [here](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop?_ga=2.21652411.1641537579.1544493429-1157548734.1544493429#3)
When I start the installation after asking for a wifi connection the installer claims there is only 4GB space and Ubuntu needs 8GB.

My guess is that it is trying to install on the USB stick for some reason.
I tried disabling secureboot, no help there.

Finally I tried changing to AHCI (from RAID on), this made the installer recognize the partition.
**But on these settings Win will not upload** (I tried and it doesn't find the boot). Before I continue with this. Will this be a problem later? If so how do I make the settings such that I can upload each OS that I choose?

Thanks
Ran

Running parted -l (while on RAID ) gives

```
    Model: SanDisk Cruzer
    Disk /dev/sda 4005MB
    Sector Size: (logical/physical) 512B/512B
    Partition table msdos
    Disk Flags:

    Number    Start    End   Size   Type   File System   Flags
    1           0    4005MB  4004MB  primary    fat32      boot,lba
```

Comment: Boot from flashdrive to Live Ubuntu (trying it out). Bring up terminal (r. click in desktop). Run command `sudo parted -l` and add output to your question.

Comment: done added to the main question

Comment: Have you updated UEFI from Dell and if SSD the SSD firmware? Have you turned off Windows fast start up and UEFI fast boot? Others:  Dell 9570 No nvidia Driver working - only one kernel version seems to work?
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2392938 & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042414/trying-to-install-ubuntu-on-dell-xps-15-9570 & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046263/dell-xps-15-9570-2018-disable-nvidia-gpu

Comment: I updated everything. Again notice that the problem is: On RAID ubuntu can't see the partition, and on AHCI windows can't upload

Comment: Are correct partition/s sizes shown on AHCI. Is Windows partition now seen? That's really what I wanted `parted -l`to look at. I don't know that much about RAID setup as I never use it. Why do you want to use that? Is your BIOS set to Legacy or UEFI?

Comment: well I don't but that was the manufacture settings, I actually want to change that and this is the problem I have that now Win is not booting

Answer (score 0):

If you are not bound with limited resources or budget then i suggest better keep additional hard drive and install ubuntu on that secondary drive. Since ubuntu will also create 3+ partitions for internal purpose and windows already occupying 2+ (most probably 3 in your case of branded pc), it may cause drive corruption or lost either os boot sector data (I am not expert but i have faced this many times). Having second os on separate drive will reduce risk of losing data of both os together.

Thanks

Comment: This is the 4th computer I am dual booting, I don't think this is a good solution for me. But thanks