# Dual booting windows 10 and Kubuntu 18.10 doesn't install the grub menu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi, kubuntu

I just bought a new Dell XPS 15 9570. It comes stock with the new Windows 10. But as I'm a developer I want to use windows for misc. tasks and a linux distro for developing stuff. So I came to the conclusion to dual boot. I have a 512 SSD, and Want to effectively split the 512GB,  260GB windows and the rest the linux distro.

Steps I've taken:

1. Created a Windows Recovery USB
2. Created a Kubuntu live usb
3. Shrank the windows volume down the required size and left ~~200GB for the linux partition
4. Booted from the Linux Live usb
5. Installed kubuntu onto the 200GB partition that was made, whilst making the bootloader part of kubuntu install into my windows bootloader partition
6. Installation finished properly
7. Rebooted computer
8. Booted into windows and I couldn't boot into the linux distro anymore

Problems I faced and solutions I tried:

1. There is no ubuntu grub. When I go into my BIOS/UEFI I can't seem to find the linux.efi file to change the boot order. But I can find the windows.efi.
2. I tried to download the grubx64.efi file from online then insert it into my bootloader partition. But that didn't seem to help either.
3. I cannot boot into the kubuntu OS even though the installation finished properly.
4. The grubx64.efi takes me directly to the grub command line.
   I tried to load the kernel from there but it didn't work. How does one get to the grub menu from there??

Is there something that I am missing that is very obvious or are there any additional steps I needed to take?

Comment: In your last line you said *grub64.efi takes you to the grub command line*, when you previously said you were booting straight to Windows. So what did you do to get to the grub prompt (I presume you mean)?

Comment: Basically I tried hacking it and copying a downloaded grub into the right place. I then changed the bootloader sequence using the bios to point to that file. That then opened the grub cli but not the menu. That's as far as I got.

Comment: In which case bring up the grub prompt then follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1077763/grub-an-error-dual-booting-windows-10-and-ubuntu-18-04/1077789#1077789). You'll need to find which partition number Kubuntu is installed on, by using command `ls (hdx, y)/` where x is disk no (probably 0) and y is partition no. If you don't see a listing for vmlinuz version, try different values for y.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) you can use the boot repair tool, I had a similar situation but with Kubuntu installed first, after using this tool the problem was solved.

Comment: Since Windows 10 pre-installed from vendor will be UEFI, be sure to boot Ubuntu live installer in UEFI to run Boot-Repair. Did you install in UEFI boot mode? How you boot install media, is then how it installs.  If not resolved, post link to Summary report from Boot-Repair. See also other 9570 installs: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042414/trying-to-install-ubuntu-on-dell-xps-15-9570 & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046263/dell-xps-15-9570-2018-disable-nvidia-gpu

Comment: yes I installed Kubuntu in the UEFI mode, then Windows 10 also in the UEFI mode, after that I coldn't boot Kubuntu, so I used this tool to fix the GRUB.

Answer (score 1):

I have also been in similar kind of issue, U just have to check whether your windows10 is installed in uefi or legacy method and then install kubuntu in same method, u can change ur method in ur boot menu