# DELL G7 15 dual boot Ubuntu 18.04 and Window 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, dell

I have a DELL G7 15, and I want to dual boot Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10.

I have carefully followed this community guide,
https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/sln301754/how-to-install-ubuntu-and-windows-8-or-10-as-a-dual-boot-on-your-dell-pc?lang=en

However, when I have followed all steps, pressed F12 to boot ubuntu and selected 'try ubuntu without install', I encountered this error...

[picture of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yt83D.jpg)

Could anyone help me to resolve this issue please?

many thanks,

Comment: You can try using the "safe graphics mode" setting. This is also called `nomodeset`. Usually you can find this option under `Other Options` (it used to be F6) to bring up this menu

Comment: Have you updated UEFI to latest from Dell? if SSD that also needs firmware update. Also drives need to be AHCI, but first install AHCI driver into Windows, then in UEFI change from RAID/Intel SRT to AHCI.  Since nVidia, you need nomodeset boot parameter. See UEFI section: https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it Dells are very similar by CPU type. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042414/trying-to-install-ubuntu-on-dell-xps-15-9570 & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046263/dell-xps-15-9570-2018-disable-nvidia-gpu

Answer (score 0):

https://www.dell.com/community/Linux-General/Ubuntu-install-on-Dell-G7-15-7588/td-p/7351194

Maybe your notebook hardware no have support Ubuntu OS

Comment: I am sure my DELL G7 7590 is supported for Ubuntu set up. I have checked the specification thought the website.