# Install Ubuntu 18.04 on Dell XPS 15 9570

Tags: system-installation, 18.04, dell

I am trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 on my Dell XPS 15 9570.

I have followed the steps provided in the [official tutorial](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0).

However, I have stumbled on an issue.

1. When I boot from USB I am immediately directed to the "Try Ubuntu" option.
   I do not manage to choose "Install Ubuntu"
   [image]

I connect to WiFi here. And then open the Install Ubuntu 18.04 icon from the desktop.

2. I select the language and the keyboard
   [image]
   [image]
3. I then press "Continue" on the following window:
   [image]
4. I get to the following window:
   [image]

If I try to press "Install Now" it tells me:
[image]
When I try to press "change" or "+" the Install window closes.

---

I suspect the issue is that I need to change the drive to ACHI mode.
But, I don't know why that would help and why can't it see the drive now.

I have create the bootable USB using Rufus 3.3 and then I have formatted it and tried again using UNetbootin.
Same issue.

Comment: What does the window with _three_ orange bullets in the lower area show (or prompt you)? You only show the second and fourth window.

Comment: @PerlDuck that window is skipped. Usually I am asked to connect to WiFi there, but since I have connected before opening the Install Ubuntu 18.04 icon, it just skipped it.

Comment: Dell needs UEFI update & if SSD an SSD firmware update. You also must change drives from RAID or Intel SRT to AHCI, but install AHCI drivers first into Windows. https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN301754/how-to-install-ubuntu-and-a-recent-windows-operating-system-as-a-dual-boot-on-your-dell-pc?lang=EN
 & https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/sln142679/how-to-enable-boot-from-dvd-option-with-uefi-boot-mode-enabled--windows-8--81--10-?lang=en
& https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042414/trying-to-install-ubuntu-on-dell-xps-15-9570

Comment: @oldfred "[...] but install AHCI drivers first into Windows". Do I need to do that if I want to install only Ubuntu, without Windows (i.e. no dual boot)?

Comment: If you are erasing Windows then no. But if totally erasing Windows I would make sure you have a good full back up of Windows. Many users later come back and say they need Windows for one application, game, school work or other requirement or later want to sell system and it then needs to be Windows.

Comment: I've called the guys from Dell and they've said that, since the laptop is new and I don't have anything on it, I could just download Windows and install it should that be the case later. And I don't need to save the Product Key, that is "injected" onto the computer motherboard at the factory.

Comment: I couldn't install Ubuntu on my dell laptop xps 15 9570 as well, but I bought a second ssd  hard disk and was able to install on that one. Now I have two hard disk in my laptop and use second only for ubuntu.

Answer (score 5):

With the help from @oldfred, I have solved the issue and installed Ubuntu 18.04 by going through the following steps:

1. Changed the driver from RAID to AHCI
2. Disabled Secure Boot
3. (Might not be needed) shrank the Windows partition