# Cannot Dual Boot Ubuntu and Windows from Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb, windows-10

I am using the Dell XPS 15 laptop, and I have Windows 10 installed. I attempted to create a dual boot from a USB and install Ubuntu to my laptop. However, I've been experiencing the same problem during installation, even though I tried launching different versions of Ubuntu from various USB devices: When I boot from the USB disk and reach the Ubuntu installation steps, my screen (and my mouse) freezes during the step of picking the partition (the partition that I created in Windows Disk Manager for Ubuntu). Because the screen freezes, the only thing I could do is to restart my laptop at this point. I couldn't find a solution to this problem on my own, I would appreciate if you could provide any suggestions with this.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I suggest checking the install media using the designed function. It'll verify the download was perfect, plus write to usb-thumb-drive.

Comment: What model XPS 15? see this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042414/trying-to-install-ubuntu-on-dell-xps-15-9570 You need UEFI & SSD firmware (if SSD) updates. You need drives set to AHCI, not RAID nor Intel SRT. If nVidia, you need nomodeset boot parameter until you install nVidia driver.

Answer (score 1):

The NVIDIA drivers included on the disc are responsible for making the system freeze. In order to mitigate this, we will need to disable them momentarily.

Highlight the 'Try Ubuntu without installing' option and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key. Add `nouveau.modeset=0`, I usually add it before `quiet splash`. Then press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot the disc. Ubuntu should respond as normal, and you should be able to install.

Once you have installed and rebooted, **PLEASE** make sure that the first thing you do after booting up, install your NVIDIA drivers. Search for the `Additional Drivers` menu by pressing the <kbd>Super</kbd> key (it's the Windows key), and searching for it.

Select the NVIDIA driver that suits you, that would usually be the `proprietary, tested` driver for your system.

[image: NVIDIA Image]

Enter your password, and once it is finished installing, reboot and you should be good to go.

Comment: Nice answer. Another generic setting is `nomodeset` in grub.