# Ubuntu 16.04 hangs on reached target shutdown/restart

Tags: 16.04, grub2, shutdown

Ubuntu 16.04 hangs on shutdown/restart I encountered this problem before but by editing the line in the /etc/default/grub from

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

to

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force"

and run

> update-grub

fixes the problem.

But after doing some heavy tasks (like web development) my laptop still hangs on shutdown/restart.

But doing some normal tasks like web browsing my device can shut and restart normally. Any suggestions?

UPDATE:
There is a time that my laptop hangs on here:
[  OK  ] Reached target shutdown
[   6431.968956   ] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI host controller not responding, assume dead
[   6431.971151   ] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0:HC died; cleaning up
[   6431.975210   ] reboot: Power down

Comment: I can not see what grub settings have to do with shutdown or with what you are doing after startup. However, sometimes I have very long shutdown times on my system as well (laptop and desktop). Long could mean 2-3minutes. After just waiting everything continues fine. No idea what it is, but I am usually very careful to force down a Linux installation on shutdown/startup. You could be causing file damage worsening your problem.

Comment: @dsstorefile I get the same Ubuntu loading hangs up. No messages.

Comment: @Catman I got the solution of the grub settings here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/764568/ubuntu-16-04-hangs-on-shutdown-restart. At first, it worked but after some time it goes back to the hang of  Ubuntu loading.

Comment: Update to this `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="verbose"` should display list of what the os is doing during boot sequence.

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz Thank you I'll do that and I update it this question after I know that is the real problem.

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowics There's no error. It says the system is ready to shutdown but it stays like that forever. I use the >GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="verbose"

Comment: Now I know, I should install the Ubuntu with an Internet so that It can better know your hardware. I have my 18.04 now and it really works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reinstalling Ubuntu on my laptop. I found the best way to avoid this problem. Make sure that when you install Ubuntu you must be connected to the internet so that Ubuntu will fully detect your hardware.