# Ubuntu 16.04 hangs on shutdown, suspend, when left idle for sometime

Tags: 16.04, suspend, shutdown

I've been using Ubuntu 16.04 for 3 months now and it was working all peachy. But, recently it started misbehaving, doesn't shut down, doesn't sleep, and earlier, when left idle the screen used to get locked and then required the password to unlock.

But now, it just simply hangs and then I have to force shutdown/reboot every time.

**Edit from comment:** current kernel version is 4.13.0-37-generic

I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764568/ubuntu-16-04-hangs-on-shutdown-restart) link and changed the grub file, but didn't work. I don't want to mess up anything else which I don't know about and don't want my computer to die. So, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What is your current kernal version? Press escape during boot and try to select other kernal.If you change your kernel during boot are you able solve the problem.

Comment: current kernel version is this - 4.13.0-37-generic

Comment: Are u able shutdown properly shutdown in previous version of kernel.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! In future,  please [edit] important info into your post as comments can be deleted without warning for numerous reasons.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be affected by [this bug.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-hwe/+bug/1751584) I suggest that you subscribe to the bug so that you can be notified about any progress.

A confirmed workaround is to boot the 4.4 series kernel which boots just fine.