# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS - Dual Boot gives problem on restart/power off of Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 18.04, lts

I've recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my SSD, on which I had installed Windows 10. My intention was to have Dual Boot systems. However, I've stumbled in a big problem.

I encountered a problem in Ubuntu: whenever I tried to restart or turn off PC, the system just froze and I couldn't do anything, except force turn off by pressing power button. To solve the problem, I've followed the instructions on this link ( [Ubuntu 16.04 hangs on shutdown/restart](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764568/ubuntu-16-04-hangs-on-shutdown-restart) ) and now I got this screen when I restart the system.

[image]

PC hangs on this screen and I'm still forced to force turn off.

Can someone help me?

PS: I know there are similar post, but none offered a reliable solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert. The thing I would try is to wipe the Ubuntu partitions and try a new clean installation from a file with checked checksums.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it wasn't a dual boot though.
(none of those other solutions i read about worked for me either)

There seem to be various causes but mine was caused by the UEFI install vs the Legacy bios install... (at boot install menu, the black screen vs the purple screen).

I took the hard drive out, put it in an older machine that had Legacy bios ONLY(to make sure i got the purple screen at boot) and installed it there. After the install was done, transferred it back to the other machine and no more shutdown problems.

I've only had this problem with that one dell pc, i've loaded 18.04 on many other machines, so it has something to do with the way the hardware/software/bios interacts after UEFI sets up the drive (on my particular pc, in my particular case).

...this may not be your issue, but it may give you another thing to try...
if i were you i'd disconnect your current hard drive(s), then put a junk drive in and install 18.04 it real quick and attempt to do a shut down. It's obvious immediately if the problem is there.
....then find a machine with legacy bios only, and take the junk drive and REDO the same install on it... transfer the drive back into your problem machine and see if it works out for you too.