# Ubuntu power off problems

Tags: 18.04, kernel, shutdown, lockup, watchdog

My laptop are asus vivobook s430u with:

I5 8250U

8gb ram

256 GB ssd

1 TB hdd

Intel hd graphic 620

Nvidia mx150

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Just installed ubuntu, I tried to shut down but it keep on freezing so I tried this solution [Ubuntu 16.04 hangs on shutdown/restart](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764568/ubuntu-16-04-hangs-on-shutdown-restart)
And it worked it didn't freeze when I turn it off but it stop at black screen and showing some error,here is the photo
[Error Photo](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EH0vM-hPF5fJfGjXMexctF83rRtw2CfO/view?usp=drivesdk)

Answer (score 0):

Never mind , turn out I found the solution
By adding nouveau.modeset=0 in the etc/default/grub and reboot it work.