# Completely stuck when Rebooting or Shutting down Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, 18.04, shutdown, xps

I'm quite the newbie Linux user, and this is the first time I'm asking a question on a forum.

I installed Ubuntu on my Dell [XPS 15 9570](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/us/en/04/xps-15-9570-laptop/xps-15-9570-setupandspecifications/specifications) in dual boot with Windows 10. I tried to install both Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 with the same results: Every single time I try to reboot or shutdown Ubuntu (Windows works fine) it gets stuck. To shut it down I need to force it by a prolonged press of the power button...

I already tried all the solutions that I found on the net including all the ones contained here: [Ubuntu 16.04 hang on shutdown/restart](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764568/ubuntu-16-04-hangs-on-shutdown-restart).

Since I needed more space I even changed the SSD and the problem occurred again, so I think that the problem couldn't be related to some faulty regions of the SSD.

I hope that I asked the question clearly and gave all the required info, of course I'm here for any additional question!

Thank you all in advance!

R

Comment: Hit the ESC key as soon as you try to restart/shutdown, and the screen will start to fill with process info that may give a clue to the problem. Look for FAIL messages, or what the last messages are before a hang. Report back.

Comment: I tried but nothing happened, the PC was completely stucked, without letting me do anything but forcing the shutdown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this problem in the past with a different Dell computer. For me, the problem was with the graphics driver. Apparently, the Xorg driver doesn't work very well with some newer GPU's and the problem manifests whenever I tried to shut down or restart my machine. The solution was to open "Software & Updates", navigate to the "Additional Drivers" tab, and select one of the proprietary drivers (e.g. NVIDIA) instead of the default Xorg one. The change requires a restart, which will hang up, but every restart after that was clean for me. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for the very detailed answer!

It was exactly as you said, I changed the drivers and the bug was fixed!

Comment: Glad to hear it!