# MSI Laptop Refusing To Shutdown

Tags: boot, dual-boot, nvidia, shutdown

I am experiencing the following issue: Today I downlaoded Ubuntu 18.04 for my MSI GP62M 7TREX LeopardPro, I had a few issues installing even(had to set acpi=off othewise it refused to boot). Just to point out, I'm using a legacy boot and I have a few issues at the moment, first one is that when I try to shutdown or sudo shutdown or sudo shutdown -h w/e. The screen freezes on the purple Ubuntu shutdown page and everytime I have to press the power button in order to turn the laptop off. I tried researching the issue, for example making some small changes in /etc/default/grub or /etc/systemd/sysctl.conf etc. I'm using the Nvidia 430 drivers for the moment I think, I'm not 100% sure as I'm currently dual booting the PC and right now I'm on my Windows 10. Can someone help me regarding the shutdown problem primarily please ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you have tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764568/ubuntu-16-04-hangs-on-shutdown-restart)

Open a terminal, type

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

change the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force"
```

and run

```
update-grub
```

Comment: I did it, after I restarted my PC, my keyboard no longer works. Now I can't do nothing and I'm locked out to my Windows 10

Comment: How can I edit the /etc/default/grub via Windows 10 now? Because I my keyboard no longer works when I select Ubuntu at the grub loader in the beginning.

Comment: It might be because slow key is enabled. hold down shift for 8 seconds will disable/enable it. You can disable that later in the system settings

Comment: In 18.04, it's in Universal Access - Typing Assist(AccessX)

Comment: Alright I managed to get the OS running by uninstalling Ubuntu. But the issue with the screen freeze still persists! Can someone suggest anything else please ?

Comment: @AlexM https://askubuntu.com/a/769972/1005646  try `sudo swapoff -a && systemctl poweroff`