# Windows 10 and Ubuntu freeze at the (blue window logo / purple screen) only if I restart from Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, windows-10

Good evening, as always thank you for your time and help.

I have this annoying problem.

**Context**

I decided to install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS in the secondary drive and Windows 10 is in the SSD.

The computer is an Alienware Area 51 R5 with the following specifications:

- 220 [GB] NVMe (Windows 10 is here)
- 2 [TB] (Ubuntu is here, in a partition of 1 [TB]. The other 1 [TB] remained untouched)
- NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080 Ti
- Intel Core i7-9800X
- RAM 32 [GB]

The installation was done following this guide:

[Dual Boot Windows 10 and Linux Ubuntu on Separate Hard Drives](https://askubuntu.com/questions/726972/dual-boot-windows-10-and-linux-ubuntu-on-separate-hard-drives)

**Problem**

Everything seemed to run smoothly. This is not the first time I have done this.
However, I discovered that if I log into Ubuntu, then I press restart, at the GRUB menu, if I choose Windows 10, Windows freezes at the very moment the blue animation appears. If instead, I choose to turn off the computer (from Ubuntu), then turn it on again, I am able to enter Windows with no problem at all.

Another tests I did were the following:

- If I log into Ubuntu, press restart, and then I choose to enter again to Ubuntu, it freezes.
- If I log into Windows, press restart, I can enter to Windows or Ubuntu without any problem.

Ubuntu is up-to-date, same for Windows. The UEFI/BIOS was updated. And before attempting to install Ubuntu the following was set as follows:

- Secure Boot is OFF
- Fast Boot is OFF.
- Hibernation is OFF.

Any ideas of what is going on and how could I solve it? I really appreciate any ideas. Thank you.

**Update (30.11.2019)**
I have tried the solution proposed by [Ubuntu Freezing at Boot Time](https://itsfoss.com/fix-ubuntu-freezing/), which is essentially change to Nvidia proprietary drivers and edit GRUB. No luck.

I also tried one of the solutions proposed in [Ubuntu 16.04 hangs on shutdown/restart](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764568/ubuntu-16-04-hangs-on-shutdown-restart) which is adding 'acpi = force' in the corresponding line of the GRUB file. No luck.

**Update 1 (01.12.2019)**
I decided to update the Linux kernel from 4.15 to 5.0. The update was successful but then again if I reboot, and attempt to enter Ubuntu, the system hangs at the purple screen. Leaving me no other choice but to do a hard-reset. After that, I'm able to enter to any OS without a problem.

Again any help is really appreciated.

The following pictures show some lines after the hard-reset is performed. The first one was before the kernel update and the second one with new kernel.

- [Some lines after hard-reset due to unsuccessful reboot (situation with Linux kernel 4.15)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBKHe.jpg)
- [Some lines after hard-reset due to unsuccessful reboot (situation with Linux kernel 5.0)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfrAi.jpg)

**Update 2 (01.12.2019)**
The same problem is present with a similar Alienware computer (AREA 51 R4) configured just like the above. Here is a picture of the interesting part of the output of the syslog file after the hard reset. The reboot was performed at 6.15 am, then it froze as always and you know the rest. Note: The timestamp is incorrect.

- [Some of the output of the syslog file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsWJz.png)

**Update (02.12.2019)**
I tried one last thing because I'm really tired of trying to find a solution. I spent a considerable amount of time of the weekend trying to solve this with no luck at all.

Well, the last thing I tried was reboot from Ubuntu and at the GRUB menu I pressed "e". At the line which starts with Linux, I added 'acpi=strict':

```
quite splash acpi=strict
```

I also tried the following combination with 'noacpi':

```
quite splash noacpi
```

And at the end of that line, I added:

```
modprobe.blacklist=nouveau
```

Nothing works. The system is running fine except that something so simple like a restart can't be done, you have to completely power off the machine.

Comment: Yes, Ubuntu freezes as well. The resume of the situation is as follows:
Every time I reboot from Ubuntu, after the GRUB menu I can't access to the selected OS. Ubuntu freezes at purple screen and Windows at the blue logo.
This does not happen if (from Ubuntu) I press 'Power Off' instead of reboot.

Comment: Does the syslog tells you something interesting?

Comment: @MelcomX Sorry for the delay, I didn't find anything relevant in the syslog file, I will be posting it. Thank you.