# Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't shutdown/suspend

Tags: boot, 16.04, suspend, shutdown, crash

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 in my Dell laptop and for the last few days I am having trouble while shutdown. So I need to press and hold the power button to turn off the system. My question is different from [Ubuntu 16.04 hangs on shutdown/restart](https://askubuntu.com/a/792086/1068577). In that question, it was asked that the system hangs at shutdown. But in my case the system doesn't hang, rather it seems that both "Suspend" and "Shut Down" doesn't function at all.

I tried the solutions suggested in the answers of the above cited question, but no solution solved the problem.

Comment: Try typing this on the terminal `sudo halt`

Comment: Actually, `sudo poweroff` is better