# Laptop keyboard and mousepad disabled on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, keyboard

I have HP Notebook-14 running Ubuntu 16.04. With external keyboard and mouse connected via USB, it works perfectly fine. However, I only discovered recently that the internal keyboard and mousepad are somehow disabled: when the external ones are removed, internal keyboard and mousepad are not responsive at all. I have no clue when this happened and how it happened. Tried turn-it-off-and-on-again several times, but the problem still persists and I am totally clueless. Could any one give me any hint?

Comment: Most laptops have either a dedicated key, or a function+f key combo to disable/enable touchpad and/or keyboard. Have you checked for this on your laptop?

Comment: @justus95 Thank you for this hint. However, I am not aware of any dedicated key on the internal keyboard that has this function. I also have no any impression that I pressed any key combo to disable keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found the smoking gun. In an [earlier attempt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764568/ubuntu-16-04-hangs-on-shutdown-restart) to resolve the issue that Ubuntu 16.04 didn't power down after clicking shutdown, I changed in file `/etc/default/grub` the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force"
```

According to this [post](https://blog.hostonnet.com/laptop-keyboard-ubuntu#:%7E:text=To%20disable%20laptop%20built%20in,the%20device%20id%20for%20keyboard.&text=xinput%20command%20should%20be%20run,(Ubuntu%20logged%20in%20user).&text=The%20ID%20is%2010.&text=Reboot%20Laptop%2C%20Built%20in%20keyboard%20will%20be%20disabled%20by%20default.), it appears that the third option might be the smoking gun. Indeed, after dropping `acpi=force` the laptop's built-in keyboard and mousepad come back top live again.