# No restart and no power off (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: grub2, shutdown, reboot, restart

I'm having a problem which is particularly embarassing. Upon shutting down my laptop (HP 255 G7) or even restarting it, I get a black screen as if the computer was really turned off but the power-on indicator is still lit; the cooling fan keeps working as well. In the end I have to press the power button to really shut it down.
I installed Ubuntu 20.04 from Windows on my HP 255 G7 some months ago but this issue appeared only around December 2021.

I already tried to edit the `/etc/default/grub` line as suggested by an user here: [Ubuntu 16.04 hangs on shutdown/restart](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764568/ubuntu-16-04-hangs-on-shutdown-restart) but without success.

This is the output of the `dmesg` command: https://file.io/NgbJAMSuxH3a

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: Are you using an IBM ThinkPad 701C? If not, could you [edit] your question to include the brand and model of your computer, as well as any information regarding how long this has been an issue? This may make it more likely that someone can offer an answer 

Comment: You're right, the question is more complete now.

Comment: Could you attach to your question the output of `dmesg`  command please?

Comment: Just attached ...

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same problem recently (about he last two weeks).  Everything seems to be working fine except trying to shutdown or restart something seems like it hangs.  I was leaning towards the harddrive but I'm a newbie so I'm not even sure how to check.

PC specs if that helps
MSI - B550M PRO-VDH WIFI
Ryzen 5 5600G
On-board graphics
WD Blue 4TB HDD
16GB 3200

If there is something else that I can share that will help root the problem out, please let me know.

Comment: How is this an answer to the question? I read it as you are asking a question which you do not do as an answer in someone else question. Make your own question.